# Pass data in an embedded ViewController from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, eureka-forms

the map is this:

> MasterVC (1) ----> DetailsVC(2) ---> EmbedVC(3)

[image: map]

I want to copy some data and fill the form in Embedded VC **before** the form it's initialized.
**MasterVC**

```
                 let vc = DetailsVC(2)
              ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                var playerValues = [String:Any]()
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    let values = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
                    playerValues = values
                    print(ref) 
                }

                vc.values = playerValues
              }
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**EmbedVC**

```
var values = [String:Any]()

viewDidLoad{
    valueTableSetup()
    }        
    func valueTableSetup() {



            form +++ Section("Position")
                <<< SegmentedRow<String>() {

                    $0.selectorTitle = "Position"
                    $0.options = ["GK","DEF","MID","ATT"]
                    $0.value =  playerValues["Position"] as? String
                    $0.tag = "Position"
                    }.onChange({ (row) in
                        let value = row.value
                        ref.updateChildValues(["Position" : value])
                    })
            form +++ Section("Preferred Side")
                <<< SegmentedRow<String>() {
                    $0.selectorTitle = "Preferred Side"
                    $0.options = ["Left","Middle","Right"]
                    $0.value = "Right"    // initially selected
                    $0.tag = "Preferred Side"
            }
    }
```

I am doing it programmatically, so no storyboards.
I also tried to pass it from the first VC(1) to EmbedVC(3), and from the (2) to (3), without results.
Everytime I try to get the value from the PlayerValues[String:Any] is nil
I am using Eureka as form builder.
I tried to download the stats into *valueTableSetup()* and also tried to run the code in ViewDidLoad, and in ViewDidAppear.

Comment: Where do you present the view controller ? How you try to pass you data ?
Anyway, if you need your data before editing the form, you need a copy of them

Comment: opss.. edited the post. I push the data from the MasterVC..when I try to copy it it gets copied after valueTableSetup() is set.

Comment: Well, I can't see the EmbedVC, but it seems to be ok your way of passing data. The problem is when you're pushing the vc. Move self.navigationController?.pushViewController into the snapshot closure, after vc.values = playerValues.
To copy values before valueTableSetup, set them into a variable before valueTableSetup is called.